# "No objects or igmages found to bake to"

Tags: texture-baking, baking

Ive searched the internet but i coudnt fix it with the answers providen.
The problem is, i canot bake my model.
I have the object selecten in normal and edit mode, the image is selected and created.

But it just doesnt let me bake it.

Comment: It wasn't necessary to export object anywhere, fbx in particular. The object in your file was set to be not-renderable (Camera icon in the Outliner editor). Enable it and bake will work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is a quite common issue that I have run into a number of times. Sometime something gets stuck and prevents you form baking properly.

Usually what I do to get around the issue is to export the object to a new project and try baking from there.

Comment: Tried that, didnt work.

Comment: Would you mind sending me a link of your project? I can take a look.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/kstn9iv0uyrt5nd/untitled.blend?dl=0

Comment: Okay I was able to get it working. Here is what I did. take your entire model and export it as A .FBX format. In Blender Click File > New to start a new file. Import the FBX in your new project and it should allow you to bake. Make sure to create a new image to bake on.